# Refresh html table using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am currently developing a simple comment section and once there is a new data inserted into the database, the table will load. Not the whole page. My question is how to refresh the table using javascript by loading the query in the same file as the javascript?

**comments.php**

```
<?php
    $getcomment = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments INNER JOIN document ON document.doc_groupid = comments.comment_doc INNER JOIN user ON user.user_matricno = comments.comment_user WHERE document.doc_id = :document ORDER BY comments.comment_timestamp DESC");
    $getcomment->bindParam(':document', $document, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $document = $_GET['doc'];
    $getcomment->execute();
    readcomment = $getcomment->fetchAll();
    $countc = $getcomment->rowCount();

    foreach ($readcomment as $rc) {
    echo 
    '
                           <table class="table table-responsive nowrap table-hover">
                           <tr>
                              <th style="border-top: #FFFFFF;pointer-events: none;">'. $rc["comment_subject"] .'</th>
                              <td class="pull-right" style="border-top: #FFFFFF;pointer-events: none;">by <strong>'. $rc["user_fname"].' '.$rc["user_lname"] .'</strong><small>&nbsp;'. time_elapsed_string($rc['comment_timestamp']).'</small></td>
                              </tr>
                             <tbody>
                               <tr>
                                 <td colspan="2">'. $rc['comment_text'] .'</td>
                               </tr>
                             </tbody>
                           </table>';
    }
?>
<div id="tablecomment"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      refreshTable();
    });

    function refreshTable(){
        $('#tablecomment').load('comments.php', function(){
           setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax to achieve this.

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

It is a bit too complex to describe in a single comment, and there are plenty of great tutorials out there. But want you want to be doing is similar to what you are already doing. Set a timout to call ajax (which gets the database data) and refresh the table with it.

Be careful to avoid race conditions where the data from a previous request arrives after a new one